# Future<String> to String into FutureBuilder and Switch statement

Tags: flutter, dart

in my application i have a simple method as future which that return `String` as `Future`:

```
Future<String> _decodeLessonUrl(BuildContext context) async {
  final ContactData data = await Provider.of<ContactDao>(context).getContacts();
  final String encryptedUrl =
      'encoded string';
  final cryptor = new PlatformStringCryptor();
  try {
    final String decrypted = await cryptor.decrypt(encryptedUrl, '${data.code}');
    return decrypted;
  } on MacMismatchException {
    return null;
  }
}
```

i want to convert this future to simple `String into FutureBuilder` and `Switch` statement:

```
FutureBuilder<PlayLessonResponse>(
    future: _myResponse,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          PlayLessonResponse response = snapshot.data;
          switch (response.status) {
            case -1: // payment is ok. show play view
              final Future<String> decodedLink = _decodeLessonUrl(context);// <-- problem is in this line
              return PlayerWidget(link:decodedLink);
          }
        }
      }
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator( ),
      );
    } ),
```

i get this error:

```
error: The argument type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

in that i couldn't use `then` because this method should be return `Widget`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For converting `Future<String>` to `String` you need to use FutureBuilder.

**Replace This:**

```
final Future<String> decodedLink = _decodeLessonUrl(context);
return PlayerWidget(link:decodedLink);
```

**With this:**

```
return FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: _decodeLessonUrl(context);
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
            return PlayerWidget(link:snapshot.data);
        }else{
            return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator( ),
            );
        }
    }
);
```